# Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Card Doesn't Work After Updating

Tags: wireless, atheros

Today I bought my first laptop with Ubuntu installed.
Everything was working, until I decided to make the update. 
I used the update manager, installed all the updates, but then my wireless stopped working.

I went to the DELL site, where I created an account, but due to the fact that some tools only work with IE (and they suggest to install it!! can't believe...), when I select my laptop model to download the drivers the answer is 0 results... Can't believe also!

I checked on the internet for a solution, but I didn't find any.
Can someone help me?

If I make a `lshw` this is what I think is the wireless info:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED description: Network controller product: QCA9565 / AR9565
Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
```

Comment: We need details about the wireless card, do you know what make/model wireless card is in the system?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Hello... my nightmare is still unresolved. Dell support is terrible also... better don't talk about that... I reinstall everything and was ok, but after the update the problem still come out... this time I wrote down exactly the Crash Report Window: Package:oem-wireless-ath9k-3.9-rc4-2-dkms

Comment: I would recommend you to report a bug, since this is not a desirable behavior of the card.

Answer (score 0):

This card is now recognised by the updated drivers backported from later kernels, so you no longer have to compile your own. To install, work out which kernel you are currently using

```
$ uname -r
3.2.0-56-generic-pae
```

Note the `generic-pae`, and install the appropriate backported driver:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.12-precise-generic-pae
```

If you have just the `generic` kernel, use

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.12-precise-generic
```

This installs the wireless drivers backported from linux kernel version 3.12. The backports repository should already be enabled in 12.04.

This is the latest version backported at the time of writing, but you can check for newer versions with:

```
apt-cache search backported wireless
```