# Lost my wireless connection after update

Tags: wireless

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and after clicking the update notification, I lost my wireless connection. I am able to connect using wired connection but not through wireless anymore.

Please help. Thanks.

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

 *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c7ffff memory:f7c80000-f7c8ffff
```

Comment: Are no wireless networks found or can you just not connect to it?

Comment: the wireless icon on my dell inspiron is not enabled.

Comment: Have a look through [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861669). It seems very similar.

Comment: Hi, the thread is for Dell with Broadcom. Will this work for me as well?

Comment: Probably not. Have a search for qualcomm linux drivers. Google lead me [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2172044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/a/384060/299997) resolved my issue.

This card is now recognised by the updated drivers backported from later
kernels, so you no longer have to compile your own. To install, work out which
kernel you are currently using

```
$ uname -r
3.2.0-56-generic-pae
```

Note the generic-pae, and install the appropriate backported driver:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.12-precise-generic-pae
```

If you have just the generic kernel, use

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.12-precise-generic
```

This installs the wireless drivers backported from linux kernel version
3.12. The backports repository should already be enabled in 12.04.

This is the latest version backported at the time of writing, but you can check
for newer versions with:

```
apt-cache search backported wireless
```

Comment: Accept answer (even if it's your own) to mark question as solved if other people are having similar problems.