# Wi-Fi adapter not working after installing updates

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, updates, kubuntu

I'm using **Kubuntu 14.04** I recently installed updates (including a kernel update) using the Muon Update Manager. Now my Wi-fi Adapter is not working.

I'm hoping some of this output will help:

**$ sudo lshw -C network**

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
description: Network controller
product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
version: 01
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:d0400000-d047ffff memory:d0480000-d048ffff
```

**lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
b43                   396480  0 
bcma                   52320  1 b43
ssb                    62352  1 b43
pci_stub               12622  1 
vboxpci                23194  0 
vboxnetadp             25670  0 
vboxnetflt             27613  0 
vboxdrv               339502  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
bnep                   19624  2 
rfcomm                 69509  8 
binfmt_misc            17468  1 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
asix                   38924  0 
usbnet                 43952  1 asix
mii                    13934  2 asix,usbnet
hid_sensor_incl_3d     13267  0 
hid_sensor_gyro_3d     13267  0 
hid_sensor_rotation    13387  0 
hid_sensor_als         13177  0 
hid_sensor_magn_3d     13267  0 
hid_sensor_accel_3d    13280  0 
hid_sensor_trigger     13134  12 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_magn_3d
industrialio_triggered_buffer    12882  6 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_magn_3d
kfifo_buf              13432  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
industrialio           54850  9 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,industrialio_triggered_buffer,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_als,kfifo_buf,hid_sensor_magn_3d
hid_sensor_iio_common    14309  6 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_magn_3d
uvcvideo               81073  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         59104  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            15681  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              153793  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
hid_sensor_hub         19877  8 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_iio_common
media                  21903  2 uvcvideo,videodev
intel_rapl             18783  0 
intel_powerclamp       18823  0 
coretemp               13441  0 
kvm_intel             143630  0 
kvm                   452096  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       14307  0 
crc32_pclmul           13133  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13230  0 
cryptd                 20359  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
ath9k                 141379  0 
joydev                 17393  0 
ath3k                  17427  0 
btusb                  32497  0 
ath9k_common           25638  1 ath9k
bluetooth             446409  23 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
ath9k_hw              446521  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
serio_raw              13483  0 
ath                    29006  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
6lowpan_iphc           18702  1 bluetooth
mac80211              652777  2 b43,ath9k
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     47548  1 
hid_multitouch         17419  0 
snd_hda_codec_conexant    23109  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    69011  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
cfg80211              498458  5 b43,ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
lpc_ich                21093  0 
snd_soc_rt5640         93042  0 
snd_soc_rl6231         13037  1 snd_soc_rt5640
shpchp                 37047  0 
snd_soc_core          200204  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_hda_intel          30469  3 
snd_hda_controller     30228  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_compress           19200  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      15172  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_codec         139719  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              17698  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               104112  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller,snd_pcm_dmaengine
mei_txe                19704  0 
mei                    87875  1 mei_txe
snd_seq_midi           13564  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30876  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                63074  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
ideapad_laptop         18278  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 ideapad_laptop
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29562  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
dw_dmac                12835  0 
snd                    79468  19 snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
dw_dmac_core           28390  1 dw_dmac
i2c_hid                18726  0 
int3403_thermal        12967  0 
soundcore              15047  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
intel_smartconnect     12637  0 
i2c_designware_platform    12979  0 
i2c_designware_core    14768  1 i2c_designware_platform
snd_soc_sst_acpi       13007  0 
8250_dw                13551  0 
spi_pxa2xx_platform    23079  0 
pwm_lpss               13214  0 
iosf_mbi               13541  0 
mac_hid                13227  0 
parport_pc             32741  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            12559  0 
usbhid                 52616  0 
hid                   110426  5 i2c_hid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic,hid_sensor_hub,usbhid
i915                  906106  3 
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
psmouse               106767  0 
drm_kms_helper         61574  1 i915
drm                   311018  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
ahci                   34142  3 
libahci                32424  1 ahci
video                  20128  1 i915
sdhci_acpi             13351  0 
sdhci                  43685  1 sdhci_acpi
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux ... 3.16.0-49-generic #65~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 9 10:03:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**rfkill list all**

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I also looked at this similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339724/atheros-qca9565-ar9565-wireless-card-doesnt-work-after-updating) but it seems to be for an older version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to disable the wrong driver that may be conflicting here:

```
sudo rmmod ath3k
```

Then run the following command **make sure to type every letter** of this command so not to overwrite the entire file:

```
echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```